# why is the springsource.com website built in drupal?

Tags: drupal, spring

I was trying to learn a little about JAVA frameworks like Spring. I hit view source on springsource.com and it's totally Drupal (a PHP CMS).

What's up with that? You would think they would build the site in their own framework, huh?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel, especially when there is something as capable as Drupal out there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because Drupal's more geared to a site of that nature, as it's a content management system instead of an application framework.  It has modules for just about everything they wanted to do.

As Colin says on [this page](http://www.springsource.org/node/69#comment-7):

> We have a very finite amount of resources which are frankly better spent on enhancing parts of Spring that are of use to the largest audience, not on modifying or implementing a CMS. While we did have to spend a decent amount of time tweaking the theme to our satisfaction, and inputing the old content, equivalent or more effort of this type would have been requiered with any solution. On the other hand, Drupal out of the box comes with all the functionality we need, so we didn't have to spend any of those scarce resources on development or customization of the product itself. It's that simple.

Answer (score 1):

I think they figured that there was more value in servicing clients than writing a CMS for their web site.  Springsource was (is?) a small company that cared about billable hours.  I think going with this software was a good business move.